# Keyboard command in shell for skipping file during copy

Tags: shell, cp

Probably a stretch but is there a keyboard command that is accepted by `cp` from the shell (using bash/zsh) to skip a currently copying file for example if I am recursively copying a folder structure of small files but forgot to exclude one big file that is taking forever, instead of ending the entire `cp` execution, excluding the file, and starting the copy over with `-n`, can I skip the file, for lack of a better term, "interactively"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can stream it all to shell in a loop:

```
for i in *; do
    printf "echo 'Copying $i...'\nsleep 1\ncp '$i' 'dir/'\n\n" | zsh
done
```

This will produce the following output (I created a temporary directory with files called **1**-**10** and a directory **dir**:

```
Copying 1...
Copying 10...
^CCopying 2...
^CCopying 3...
^CCopying 4...
^CCopying 5...
^CCopying 6...
^CCopying 7...
^CCopying 8...
^CCopying 9...
```

Before streaming to `zsh`, make sure the commands do what you want.